# Windows 2008 server not authorizing vpn traffic

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, authorization

We are struggling to setup windows 2008 server vpn.

We have managed to establish a connection to the server from the client pc but cant browse to any url on the same server.

We keep getting an error on the client that authorization failed.

The servers event viewer is also reporting an error. The error is

```
An IPsec quick mode negotiation failed.

Local Endpoint:
Network Address:    0.0.0.0
Network Address mask:   0.0.0.0
Port:           0
Tunnel Endpoint:        <server ip address>

Remote Endpoint:
Network Address:    <dhcp assigned ip address>
Address Mask:       0.0.0.0
Port:           0
Tunnel Endpoint:        <client public ip address>
Private Address:        0.0.0.0

Additional Information:
Protocol:       0
Keying Module Name: IKEv1
Virtual Interface Tunnel ID:    0
Traffic Selector ID:    0
Mode:           Tunnel
Role:           Responder
Quick Mode Filter ID:   0
Main Mode SA ID:    3740

Failure Information:
State:          No state
Message ID:     3992574641
Failure Point:      Local computer
Failure Reason:     No policy configured
```

We have setup the server to use a preshared key and dont use a username or password to connect  from the client.

**Where do we setup a policy to authorize the traffic or authenticate quick mode.**

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb794765.aspx):

Cause: The IPsec network range combines several physical networks with adjacent ranges. If you configure a remote site network, which actually comprises two different networks with adjacent IP address ranges in the same subnet, connections cannot be initiated to either network.

Solution: To avoid this, create two remote site IPsec networks, one for each physical network. Then create appropriate network and access rules for each remote site.

So, you need access rules for each network.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Are you able to help point us the right direction where we can setup or add these remote networks. Do we need a physical adapter or can we add a new interface in RRAS?